# I can't compile the rest after inputed the age in eclipse, it says "Terminated" on console. Does anyone know how to solve the problem ? Thanks

Tags: java, date, console, terminate, terminate-handler

'What i am trying to do::
Show message based on

Good morning (12am-12pm)
Good after noon (12pm -4pm)
Good evening (4pm to 9pm)
Good night ( 9pm to 6am)'

```
import java.util.Calendar;
```

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class inputers {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    GregorianCalendar time = new GregorianCalendar();
      int hour = time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
      int min = time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
      int day = time.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
      int month = time.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
      int year = time.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    
    String name, address;
    int age;
    String greeting;
    
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Address: ");
    address = input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.print("age: ");
    age = input.nextInt();
    
    if(hour>=1 && hour<=11){
        greeting = "Morning";
    } else if(hour<=15){
        greeting = "Afternoon";
    } else if(hour<=24){
        greeting = "Evening";
                        
        
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Good " + greeting + ", " + name);
        System.out.println("are you sure that you're " + age + " years ?" );
        System.out.println("and live on " + address);
                
        }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wait until the hour of day is greater than 15, because all you output happens in the `else if (hour<=24)` case.

Or you could move the output out of this code block:

```
    } else if(hour<=24) {
        greeting = "Evening";
    } else {
        greeting = "Night";
    }

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Good " + greeting + ", " + name);
    System.out.println("are you sure that you're " + age + " years ?" );
    System.out.println("and live on " + address);
```